# Including power bi on a microsoft teams custom app

Tags: microsoft-teams, custom-application

I'm building a custom app for ms teams and I would like to include another tab with power bi.
For example, on the teams chat we can click the '+' to add a new tab and add power bi app.

Can we include the '+' button on a custom app to do the same or can we include a power bi tab out of the box?

Tks

Comment: You can't add '+' button on custom app you need to have power bi tab as a separate tab.

Comment: so, the only way would be to create a new tab and embed the power bi dashboard? or is there another option?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new tab and embed the power bi dashboard.